# jquery / elevatezoom on newly added image

Tags: jquery

I'm working on tabulating a large data set, which contains images which will be the first column in the table. Loading all the full-sized images at once is unworkable, so I have the table set up with pagination, and images are only inserted when the rows are made visible:

```
  tableContent += '<tr>';
  tableContent += '<td><span id="photofield_' + filename + '"></span></td>';
```

and then when ready to display:

```
function placePhoto(filename) {
  document.getElementById('photofield_'+filename).innerHTML = '<img id="tzoom' + filename + '" src="images/' + filename  + '" data-zoom-image="images/big_' + filename + '" width="100" class="initzoom">';
}
```

This works fine for loading and displaying the images as required.

Before I started with the pagination, I was using the jquery plugin elevateZoom, which was as simple as

```
$("#img_01").elevateZoom();
```

and which worked fine for images added after the $(document).ready call. However, it doesn't work for the elements added by placePhoto when I add the following:

```
$('body').on('click','img.initzoom',initzoom)


function initzoom(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("#"+this.id);
  $("#"+this.id).elevateZoom();
}
```

Everything looks fine, the alert pops up with the id matching that in the added img, but there's no apparent effect.

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Or if not, where could I go next to troubleshoot?

Comment: Did you wraped the function in $(document).ready? maybe you fire the event before the html was loaded

Comment: @Ilan You mean the on('click') function? It's in $(document).ready and seems to do the job (the alert gets shown on click for the newly added elements)